# Nutch giving java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not implemented by the DistributedFileSystem FileSystem implementation

Tags: nutch

I am using the following stack while using Nutch for web crawling:

- Hadoop: 2.5.2
- Hbase: 0.98.12-hadoop2
- Gora: 0.6.1

But when I am injecting the url by this command:

```
hadoop@ubuntu:~$ nutch inject /home/gsingh/urls/seed.txt
```

I am getting the following error.

```
> InjectorJob: starting at 2016-05-19 11:12:57 InjectorJob: Injecting
> urlDir: /home/gsingh/urls/seed.txt InjectorJob:
> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not implemented by the
> DistributedFileSystem FileSystem implementation
>         at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getScheme(FileSystem.java:214)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.loadFileSystems(FileSystem.java:2559)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2569)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2586)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:89)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2625)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2607)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:368)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:167)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:352)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:296)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.addInputPath(FileInputFormat.java:372)
>         at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.run(InjectorJob.java:212)
>         at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.inject(InjectorJob.java:252)
>         at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.run(InjectorJob.java:275)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
>         at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.main(InjectorJob.java:284)
```

Following is the classpath value:

```
hadoop@ubuntu:~$ echo $CLASSPATH
/usr/local/nutch/runtime/local/lib/*:.
```

Anybody has any idea how to rectify this error?

Comment: Did you get the solution ?